# What is the expected behavior of a Docker multi-stage build when an error is present in a stage that is not used?

Tags: docker, docker-multi-stage-build

My Dockerfile is the following:

```
FROM alpine AS notused
RUN chmod +x hello
FROM alpine
CMD ["echo", "hello"]
```

On my machine, output of the build is (Docker engine 20.10.10):

```
Step 1/4 : FROM alpine AS notused
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
59bf1c3509f3: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:21a3deaa0d32a8057914f36584b5288d2e5ecc984380bc0118285c70fa8c9300
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest
 ---> c059bfaa849c
Step 2/4 : RUN chmod +x hello
 ---> Running in 9a9d60e84b37
chmod: hello: No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c chmod +x hello' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

My colleague tried the same thing and strangely enough, with the same Docker version, the build passes (probably because the stage that is not used is not executed).

What is the expected behavior and why such a difference?